# How to find all commits containing the exact file with exact contents?

Tags: git

I am trying to find out a way on how to search for a file on git repo with the exact contents (100% match). Suppose I have this simple scenario:

- I create a new git repo locally. Create a text file name:
  myFile.txt with a content "1". And commit it to the repo. Just for
  sake of simple example, the first four letters of the SHA-1 hash is
  "1111".
- Then I modified the myFile.txt with a content "2" and commit to the
  repo. SHA-1 will be "2222".
- Then I modified it again with a content "3" and commit to the repo.
  SHA-1 will be "3333".
- Now, I modified the file and put a content "1". This time I will not commit yet.

How will I be able to know in which commit myFile1.txt has the same contents on all the previous commits? Is there a command to do that? e.g.

```
git-find-the-file   myFile.txt
output: The same file is on commit "1111"
```

I wish to use it on finding text and binary files. My actual application is finding the same word documents on a Git Repo with more than 100 commits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to see all changes related to that file.

`gitk myFile.txt`

Comment: Hi thank you for the suggestion, that gitk was something new for me. I am playing with it currently. Although I edited my question and added the information where I will be using it (finding same word document files on a Git repo with more than 100 commits). I will do testing on Gitk now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try

```
git log --raw --abbrev=40 --pretty=oneline |
    grep -B 1 `git hash-object filename`
```

Reference: [Git User Manual-Finding commits referencing a file with given content](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual/2.2.1)

Comment: That `--raw` option's pretty sweet here, but I think the grep will fail if the file isn't the first one changed, you want ``git log --raw --abbrev=40 --pretty=%H | awk 'NF==1{commit=$1} $4==hash{print commit}' hash=`git hash-object myfile.txt` ``

Comment: @jthill thanks for pointing it out. I could not access the computer right now, so I'll update it when I'm able to verify the answer.

Comment: @jthill  that was perfect. I tried it with bitmap file and it returns correctly. exactly what I was looking for.



$ git log --raw --abbrev=40 --pretty=%H | awk 'NF==1{commit=$1} $4==hash{print commit}' hash=`git hash-object a.bmp`

0b95661c89b0c0b2a65acc3abeaf0707f1474a46

0d681eeda1b6add2912657ad8a084fef92097fd2


Thank you so much. It works both on a committed and an un-commited file.

Answer (score 0):

```
myfile=`git hash-object myfile.txt`
git rev-list HEAD | while read rev; do 
        [[ `git rev-parse $rev:myfile.txt` = $myfile ]] && echo $rev
done
```

If you want to check against the last-staged aka last-added content rather than the current worktree content, substitute `git rev-parse :myfile.txt` for the hash-object.

Answer (score 0):

As a personal challenge and to try out the Python git module, I created a small Python program that should do this as well.  Install the Python git module first and then run it as "findFile.py pathToRepo pathToFileToFind" and it will list all commits and the path the found file in the repo. Note that this should find all instances of the file (even if its renamed since it searches based on the SHA of the file) and in any path within the repo.

Its at https://github.com/dneiss/findFile.

Answer (score 0):

To find all commits containing the exact file with exact contents, you can use the git log command with the --all and --grep options.

Use the following command to search for commits containing the exact file with exact contents:

`git log --all --grep='<content>' -- <file>`